# Can i use init hook for API purpose?

Tags: plugins, api, init

My question title might be little confuse. Here is the scenario, For example: I am giving an API service from my wordpress site.

Using it others can know few information. Like if they send a User ID in query URL then i'll send them user phone number.

For Example: If they access the site with `www.example.com/?cuid=23`

Now on `init` hook i'll check if `cuid` is present in `$_GET` variable, if it is present then i'll get phone number and die the function with phone number. Since `init` hook is the earliest hook i choose to use it.

```
function tell_phone_num(){
         if(isset($_GET['cuid'])){
         //some one wants the service 
          //I'll get the phone number and show it -> $user_phone
         //setting response format, like json etc
          die($user_phone);
          }
}
add_action('init','tell_phone_num');
```

This works fine. When site is accessed with `cuid` then only this function will work.

This is just an example but phone number is not my real information. I don't need authentication because the information i am giving in are not sensitive.

Here is my question. Is this correct way to do or should I do some other best practice method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more user-friendly URL structure, you could [add a rewrite endpoint](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

This will add the rules for and intercept requests to `/my-api/`:

```
function wpd_add_api_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my-api', EP_ROOT );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_api_endpoint' );

function wpd_api_request( $request ){
    if( isset( $request->query_vars['my-api'] ) ){

        // $request->query_vars['my-api'] is a string containing everything after your url slug
        // convert it to array
        $parts = explode( '/', $request->query_vars['my-api'] );

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $parts );
        echo '</pre>';

        die;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_api_request' );
```

After you flush rules, try a request like:

> http://example.com/my-api/something/else/123/4,5,6/&7

Which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => something
    [1] => else
    [2] => 123
    [3] => 4,5,6
    [4] => &7
)
```

Comment: Thanks +1. Beside these friendly version. Is there any security or overload to wordpress if do it in `init` using the `$_GET` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `init` is good for this purpose. In [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) is written:

> init is useful for intercepting $_GET or $_POST triggers.

Comment: +1. I can understand that we could use `$_GET` or `$_POST` in init hook. Is it good to use the `die` function on `init` using this `$_GET`

Comment: If you don't want to do anything more, just echoing the value and kill WP loading, why not.